# std::accumulate() only the real part of a complex std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, vector, complex-numbers

I used to take the sum of a symmetric (Hermitian) matrix (the matrix is in an `std::vector`), which is a huge waste because the imaginary part will always add to zero (I'm talking about huge matrices with side-length of `n>1000`, so I think it makes a difference.

So now I only add the upper-triangular part of the matrix. But I want to optimize this further and avoid adding the complex part because I don't need it.

What I currently use is:

```
std::real(std::accumulate(myMatrix.begin(), myMatrix.end(), std::complex<Real>(0,0)));
```

This adds all the element of `myMatrix` to `std::complex<Real>(0,0)`, resulting in the sum I need.

But this will add real and imaginary components of my vector, which is a waste! How can I write the most optimized version of this that adds only the real part of this matrix?

---

**UPDATE:**

While I accepted the answer that works, I discovered that it's slower than summing the real and imaginary parts of my matrix. It's slower by 5%-10% for a matrix with side-length of 128. This is surprising. Any other faster suggestions are highly appreciated.

Please ask if you require additional information.

Comment: Please explain if you `-1` this post. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you ever considered std::thread based parallel or cuda? Plus, for a symmetric matrix, you only need to visit n(n-1)/2 elements, instead of n*n elements to make an accumulation.

Comment: @FengWang Actually I'm parallelizing with OpenMP, and I'm visiting n(n-1)/2 elements already :)

Comment: With simple aggregations of large arrays, the performance bottleneck really is in the memory bandwidth. How many bytes is a `Real`? If `Real` is defined as a 4 bytes float, a 64 bit machine might load 8 aligned bytes as fast as only the first 4 bytes thereof. You could test this by separating myMatrix into a real and an imaginary part, both represented by `std::vector<float>` and then only aggregate the real part, but that is ony beneficial if you don't have to translate between different representations a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Real real_sum = std::accumulate(
    myMatrix.cbegin(), myMatrix.cend(), Real{},
    [](Real const acc, std::complex<Real> const& c) { return acc + std::real(c); }
);
```

Comment: By the way, I just found out that this is computationally slower :(

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist : Try `[](Real& acc, std::complex<Real> const c) -> Real& { return acc += c.real(); }` – does it perform any differently?

Comment: Still... this is slower than the sum of real and imaginary part together by 5%-10%... I'm really surprised.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Possibly the complex-adding version got SIMD'd

Answer (score 4):

[`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) has two overloads, one of which takes an operator:

```
template< class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init,
              BinaryOperation op );
```

Just provide your own instead of defaulting to `+`:

```
std::accumulate(myMatrix.begin(), myMatrix.end(), Real{0},
    [](Real const& sum, std::complex<Real> const& next){
        return sum + std::real(next);
    });
```

---

Alternatively, you could do something fun like use [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
auto make_real = [](std::complex<Real> const& c) {
    return std::real(c);
};

std::accumulate(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myMatrix.begin(), make_real),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myMatrix.end(), make_real),
    Real{0});
```

Or with [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
accumulate(myMatrix,
    Real{0},
    std::plus<>{},
    [](std::complex<Real> const& c) { return c.real(); }
);
```

Both of the above would be much nicer if `real` didn't have overloads and you could just provide `std::real<Real>` in the boost example and `&std::complex<Real>::real` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Is using `std::accumulate` absolutely necessary?

```
    Real acc = 0;
    for(auto c : myMatrix)
       acc += real(c);
```

Don't get me wrong, I'm in favour of using standard algorithms when they suit, but it seems hard to beat this loop in readability.

This is as compared to the implementation that came with my g++-4.8.4 install:

```
  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp
    accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
      __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

      for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    __init = __init + *__first;
      return __init;
    }
```

So you can see they're pretty much doing the same thing.

Comment: std algorithms are optimized for processors. So yes, if you want the best outcome, you should use std algorthms as much as possible.

Comment: By using `auto c` instead of `auto& c` you're making copies. Was that your intent?

Comment: @kfsone I trust the compiler to make that optimization of avoiding the copy.